# JPA and DAO - what's the standard approach?

Tags: spring, jpa, dao

I'm developing my first app with JPA/Hibernate and Spring. My first attempt at a DAO class looks like this:

```
@Repository(value = "userDao")
public class UserDaoJpa implements UserDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public User getUser(Long id) {
        return em.find(User.class, id);
    }

    public List getUsers() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("select e from User e");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

I also found some examples using `JpaDaoSupport` and `JpaTemplate`. Which design do you prefer? Is there anything wrong with my example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say your approach looks totally sound. Personally I don't use `JpaDaoSupport` or `JpaTemplate` because you can do everything you need with the `EntityManager` and Criteria Queries.

Quote from the [JavaDoc of JpaTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTemplate.html):

> JpaTemplate mainly exists as a sibling of JdoTemplate and HibernateTemplate, offering the same style for people used to it. For newly started projects, consider adopting the standard JPA style of coding data access objects instead, based on a "shared EntityManager" reference injected via a Spring bean definition or the JPA PersistenceContext annotation.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the template-less approach (i.e. your current approach) because

- it's less invasive, you don't tie DAOs to Spring
- templates don't offer much value with APIs that use unchecked exceptions

And this is the Spring recommendation, as summarized in the blog post "[So should you still use Spring's HibernateTemplate and/or JpaTemplate??](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/)" and the official javadoc:

> #### The real question is: which approach to choose??
>
> (...)
>
> So in short (as the JavaDoc for
>   `HibernateTemplate` and
>   [`JpaTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTemplate.html) already mention)
>   I'd recommend you to start using the
>   `Session` and/or `EntityManager` API
>   directly if you're starting to use
>   Hibernate or JPA respectively on a new
>   project–remember: Spring tries to be
>   non-invasive, this is another great
>   example!

Comment: +@Pascal ho do I inject entityManager in dao ? I am relatively new to spring. can you please point me to application.xml reference for the same ? I am using hibernate and these dao are in webapplication (so spring webappcontext needs to be used ?)

Answer (score 2):

I, personally, prefer your approach - inject `EntityManager` and use it directly. But `JpaTemplate` is also a good option. I don't like it, because adds yet another, unnecessary layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a "standard" approach.

If you're using JPA, you have your choice of implementations: Hibernate, TopLink, etc.

If you deploy to Google App Engine, you'll use JPA talking to BigTable.

So if your objectives are to maximize portability, stick with the JPA standard, and not tie yourself to a particular implementation like Hibernate, make sure that your DAOs only use JPA constructs.

Comment: Sorry Pascal, if I recall correctly this isn't the first time you've had to point that out to me.  I have expunge that idea from memory.  Error corrected - thank you.

Comment: I hope this public embarrassment sticks with me a bit longer.  8)    And stop it - you're sparking my iPad envy.  It's too early in the day for that...

Comment: I removed the public embarrassment, I was feeling bad :)

Comment: No worries - it's the only way it'll have a hope of sticking.